# Necessary permissions to the synchronization account in AD

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

Configure  the  User  Profile  Synchronization  service  to  import  user profile data from Active Directory. and

- Grant the User Profile service account the least permissions necessary to read data

so below which permission i will add to user profile service account for User Profile Synchronization connection

1. Grant the account Read permission on the domain.
2. Grant the account the Replicate Directory Changes permission on the domain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exam questions are off topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account which you use to connect to AD( entering while establishing the connection with AD), It must have Replicate Directory Changes permission on the domain with which you’ll synchronize.

> The Replicate Directory Changes permission allows an account to query
>   for the changes in the directory. This permission does not allow an
>   account to make any changes in the directory.

[Grant Active Directory Domain Services permissions for profile synchronization in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)